# Gmail account becomes locked down after downloading many attached files in emails

Tags: gmail, google-account

I was trying to download the scanned PDF files attached to my previous emails in my Gmail account. Each scanned PDF file is about 10MB, and there are quite a few of them. After downloading some, my Gmail account became locked down.

> Unusual Usage - Account Temporarily Locked Down
>
> To keep our systems healthy, Google has temporarily disabled your
>   account. This primarily occurs when we detect unusually high levels of
>   activity on your account. In most cases, it should take one hour to
>   regain access. In rare cases, it can take up to 24 hours for access to
>   be reinstated.

It has been locked down for two hours, and i can't afford waiting for 24 hours for access to be reinstated.

How shall I do then? Does Gmail have a customer service phone number which I can call for immediate assistance?

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

Wait a bit (an hour) and try again. Repeat as necessary.

## Long answer

### Explanation

The Gmail consumer accounts support options could vary from time to time and due to other factors like location and language and day time.

First, take a look to the [Gmail Help Center](http://support.google.com/mail) for a "Contact us" link. If it's not there search for a help article related to your issue. If you are lucky, a pop-up will be displayed offering you to chat with a support agent.

The next thing to try is to post a question in the [Gmail help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail). Bear in mind that getting help to be in touch with a Gmail support agent could take a while and that there is no guarantee that it will occur.

As far as I know, even been able to get in touch with a Gmail support agent, the user of a locked-down account should wait until the access being automatically reinstated.

### How to prevent this from occurring again

Instead of downloading a large number of attachments manually in a short time, use one or several of the following alternatives:

- Add the attachments to Google Drive then use Google Drive for Mac/PC (see [2])
- Use a desktop email client to access the account by IMAP and download all the messages to the local drive (see [3])
- Use Google Takeout (see [4])

**References**
1. [Contact us - Google](http://www.google.com/contact/)
2. [Attachments: View, download, and save - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30719?hl=en)
3. [Get started with IMAP and POP3 - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en)
4. [Dowload your data - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)

Comment: thanks. in Gmail Help Center there is no "Contact us" link. my issue is not there. Is it possible that I can chat with a support agent, and how?

Comment: As you already posted a question to the Gmail Help forum, wait for an reply there with instructions. Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that this will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't offer a traditional customer support line. They use what most web-based companies use: FAQ pages and support articles.

Contact options, including email, are available at http://www.google.com/contact/

Comment: thanks. I can't find their email address. What is it?

Comment: @contracode: Missed to mention the [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail) .

Comment: @Ruben: I tried, no one replied. I am desperate.

Comment: and obviously what they offer is insufficient