# Gmail won't let me in despite correct password (device not recognized)

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

Gmail won't let me sign in to my old account which I haven't used for years (last time used probably even in different country). After providing correct password it responds with:
[image]

I don't have this phone number since forever and I haven't used it for any two-factor authentication.

When I go to "Need help recovering password?" I'm asked for password again after which Google responds **"Google couldn't verify this account belongs to you"**.

I can go to mail recovery but it's useless as in the proces I'm asked to read the code on old phone again.

Even when I try to recover account through linked mail it still asks me read the code on phone.

This is effectively causing a deadlock. Is there really no way around it? Does gmail human support exist?

Comment: Related : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80180/88163

Comment: @Rubén it's not helpful, Google claims "You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can." but it doesn't ask me any questions at all, only requires pin sent to phone which I do not have.

Comment: Have you read my answer to the related question thoroughly? It mentions that the help center under certain circumstances could show you a button to contact Gmail support. Nowadays they could mention Google One.